# Linking SFML in CodeLite

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, sfml, codelite

Ok so I am trying to link SFML in a CodeLite project but with no success. So what have I done :

1. Added the include folder of SFML to the IncludePaths of CodeLite.
2. Added the lib folder of SFML to the LibrariesSearchPath of CodeLite.
3. Added SFML_STATIC to Preprocessors in CodeLite.
4. Added the libraries to the LinkerOptions like this :

   ```
   sfml-graphics;sfml-window;sfml-audio;sfml-network;sfml-system
   ```
5. Added the 5 dll's(sfml-graphics-2.dll.. etc) to the debug folder and to the project folder

This is the build log :
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C ""E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW    /bin/mingw32-make.exe" -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile""
    "----------Building project:[ Test - Debug ]----------"
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'F:/Dropbox/Programming/OpenGL/Test'
    "E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" -o ./Debug/Test @"Test.txt" -L. -LF:/Dropbox/Programming/SFML/SFML-2.3.2x86/lib   sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-audio sfml-network sfml-system
    g++.exe: error: sfml-graphics: No such file or directory
    g++.exe: error: sfml-window: No such file or directory
    g++.exe: error: sfml-audio: No such file or directory
    g++.exe: error: sfml-network: No such file or directory
    g++.exe: error: sfml-system: No such file or directory
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/Test] Error 1
    Test.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/Test' failed
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/Dropbox/Programming/OpenGL/Test'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
    Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
    ====1 errors, 0 warnings====`

I am using CodeLite 9.0.9 and SFML-2.3.2x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to fix it by changing the libraries like this : `-lsfml-graphics-s;-lsfml-window-s;-lsfml-audio-s;-lsfml-network-s;-lsfml-system-s;-lopengl32;-lfreetype;-ljpeg;-lwinmm;-lgdi32;-lopenal32;-lws2_32`

Answer (score 2):

**1**. "Starting from SFML 2.2, when static linking, you will have to link
    all of SFML's dependencies to your project as well. This means that
    if you are linking sfml-window-s or sfml-window-s-d for example, you
    will also have to link opengl32, winmm and gdi32. Some of these
    dependency libraries might already be listed under "Inherited
    values", but adding them again yourself shouldn't cause any
    problems." 
**Your linked libraries should have -s suffix if you're linking statically and you should link other libraries look at [this](http://screenshot.sh/mFdmc5gNWnwCt).**

**2**."When linking to multiple SFML libraries, make sure that you link them in the right order, it is very important for GCC. The rule is that libraries that depend on other libraries must be put first in the list. Every SFML library depends on sfml-system, and sfml-graphics also depends on sfml-window. So, the correct order for these three libraries would be: sfml-graphics, sfml-window, sfml-system -- as shown in the screen capture above." **Set linking order to graphics-s/window-s/system-s/etc**

**3**."It is important to link to the libraries that match the configuration: "sfml-xxx-d" for Debug, and "sfml-xxx" for Release. A bad mix may result in crashes."
**From your build log I can see that you're building your project as Debug with Release libraries(those without -d suffix), then you have to change linked libraries to sfml-graphics-s-d/etc**

If advices above won't work then you set search paths wrong. Good luck

Comment: Ok I changed the linked libraries to this : sfml-graphics-s;sfml-window-s;sfml-audio-s;sfml-network-s;sfml-system-s;glew;opengl32;freetype;jpeg;winmm;gdi32;sndfile;openal32;ws2_32; <br> And I am now building the project as Release but it is still saying it can't find the files for any of those libraries

Comment: Try linking sfml libraries as libsfml-graphics-s;libsfml-window-s; and so on. Add lib prefix to them(only to sfml libs, not opengl/etc)

Comment: What about adding .lib ? for example sfml-graphics-s.lib

Comment: Still nothing. But I don't think the problem is in this because why would it not be able to find even `opengl32` ?

Comment: It does work for me. My linker options [libs](http://screenshot.sh/mFdmensp527Tz) , and codelite ignores sfml_static preprocessor so in the code you have to #define SFML_STATIC :)
[look](http://screenshot.sh/oAE3RoJTzDRRn)

Comment: This solves my problems after days of literally pulling my hair out. Note for the confused: opengl32, winmm and gdi32 are part of Windows Operating System. So you only need to add to your g++ compilation line this: C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dl